# У Вас есть на улице возможность интернет/Интернет раздавать?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> У Вас есть на улице возможность интернет/Интернет раздавать?

Comment: Вопрос составлен корректно, проблема обозначена: выбор прописной или строчной буквы. Нужно сделать выбор (или посмотреть существующее решение в текстах на эту тему) и объяснить по правилам. Я даже видела записи в кавычках, но таких мало.  Еще одна проблема: это терминологическое сочетание или его разговорный вариант?  Доп. вопрос:  английское соответствие термина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   – Я с трудом понимаю, зачем сегодня нужны журналисты, – 
   сообщил Супермен коллективу. – Вся информация есть в 
   Интернете, бери да читай. 
   Из современной литературы (2015 год)
```

Правильно **со строчной буквы:**

*У Вас есть на улице возможность **интернет раздавать**?*

**Пояснение**

1. В данном сочетании имеется в виду раздавать **интернет-соединение**, а это слово в орфографическом словаре РАН пишется со строчной буквы.
2. В общем случае существует **две формы записи** по словарю: **Интернет** как Всемирная компьютерная сеть и **интернет** как разговорный вариант.

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

Статья:  **[Как легко раздать интернет с любого смартфона?](https://dzen.ru/a/Y-t7CBH7mCGa4LH1)**

**ИНТЕРНЕТ** Русский орфографический словарь:
**Интернет**, -а и **интернет**, -а

**ИНТЕРНЕТ** Русский орфографический словарь:
**интернет-...** – первая часть сложных слов, пишется через дефис

**ИНТЕРНЕТ-СОЕДИНЕНИЕ**:
Русский орфографический словарь
**интернет-соединение**, -я

Большой толковый словарь

**ИНТЕРНЕТ** [тэрнэ], -а; м. [англ. Internet от international net - международная сеть]. 1. [с прописной буквы] **Всемирная компьютерная сеть** (информационная система связи, объединяющая множество компьютеров во всём мире). Выйти в И. Открыть собственный сайт в Интернете. 2. **Разг. Система связи** для получения и передачи цифровой информации. Заплатить за и. Установить дома и.

**РАЗДАТЬ**, св. кого-что (кому). Отдать, выдать всё, многое, **распределить между всеми, многими.** Р. деньги, зарплату, долги. Р. книги. Р. подарки детям. Р. котят. Р. ордена. Р. должности. Р. заказы, чай. // Поручить нескольким, многим исполнение чего-л. Р. поручения детям. Р. работу заводам. Р. роли актёрам. Р. приказания (приказать).

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение и за голос)